# Communication from Pod to Pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a node with 2 pods. Each pod will need to speak to each other. Problem being that i do not want to hardcode the IPs in for the communication.

Similar to a DNS service, i need something (that does not change) that can sit above the pod ip and allow me to still communicate between the pods.

Comment: Read up on the service. User the service to abstract away a set of pods sharing a set of labels

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can see two solution

**Solution 1:** Use Service

If they are not from same controller and if they have their own Service, they can use Service to communicate with each other.

```
Service 1 - > Pod 1
Service 2 - > Pod 2
```

Use this Service

```
Pod 1: Service 2 -> Pod 2
Pod 2: Service 1 -> Pod 1
```

**Solution 2:** Use StatefulSet

If they need same Controller, you can use [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/).

> For a StatefulSet with N replicas, each Pod in the StatefulSet will be assigned an integer ordinal, in the range [0,N], that is unique over the Set

That means Pod name will be: `$(statefulset name)-$(ordinal)`

If you have StatefulSet named `nginx` with replica 2, you will have two Pod `nginx-0` & `nginx-1`.

> As each Pod is created, it gets a matching DNS subdomain, taking the form: `$(podname).$(governing service domain)`

**Pod `nginx-0`:** `nginx-1.{service-account}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local` -> **`nginx-1`**

**Pod `nginx-1`:** `nginx-0.{service-account}.{namespace}.svc.cluster.local` -> **`nginx-0`**

Using this [Stable Network ID](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id), these Pods can communicate with each other.

Comment: I tried out solution one and it works well. I used `externalIPs` and it communicated smoothly between each other. Thanks

Comment: Can you show us how did you use externalIPs? As far I know they are not hostnames